# Drupal CSS broken in Internet Explorer 7/8, but works as static page

Tags: theming

The CSS layout on my Drupal site was suddenly found to be broken in IE 7 & 8. No idea what happened to cause this, but the strange thing is, if I save the source/files, then upload and test as a static page, it works fine (well, good enough for Internet Explorer). I'm using Adobe BrowswerLab to test.
I've turned off caching in performance and boost. I have also turned gzip compression off on the server, and added 10 second delay to browserlab load-time. Nothing seems to make the CSS work straight from the actual site.
I haven't found any threads about this specifically. Does anybody know what might be going on?

I am using Drupal 6.24.

Comment: Well, could you give us something concrete, like code or a website URL? I don't want to break into your house to debug this...

Comment: Oops yes: www.worldyoganetwork.com

Answer (score 4):

Do you have CSS and Javascript caching enables? IE7 & IE8 can only load a certain amount of external files and you maybe exceeding the limit. Retry with CSS and JS caching enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too in a Drupal Commons 6x24 site: On a quick step I did toggle the CSS-aggregation, and switched it off.

Just have a closer look at this, here: Your lack of styles on the site is due to inadequate file permissions on your server. Your site is unable to save the auto-generated compressed CSS file, thus there is no style information to be displayed.

Installing a different theme would do nothing to fix this situation. If you cannot manage to get the proper files permissions set up, you may try disabling CSS aggregation by navigating to Administration -> Site Configuration -> Performance, and toggling off the CSS aggregation setting, then clicking the save button.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your source code and the number of modules noted in your jquery settings, it does look this is the IE CSS loader limit issue. IE will load 32 css files and only 32 -- any more than that and it just quits and refuses to load any. Here is a good testbed of this issue:

http://john.albin.net/ie-css-limits/993-style-test.html

When developing for IE, you will need to temporarily turn off css aggregation (which is on in your site) to get the styles to load. Another option (for Drupal 6.x) is to install the unlimted css loader module:

http://drupal.org/project/unlimited_css

Which offers another option around this.

Comment: hi there - many thx for the  great answer! Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Also you could open the css file in another tab and check if IE found it or if return a error or something like that.

Sometime this happened to me when the css file had another encoding.